# Rellenar array con consulta de base de datos

Tags: php

Estoy intentando rellenar un array con los datos recogidos de una consulta de base de datos, pero no lo consigo. Alguien  me podría echar una mano.

```
 $consulta="SELECT * FROM $producto ORDER BY $parametro DESC LIMIT 10";        

    $resultado = mysqli_query ($miconexion, $consulta) 
                            or die("No se puede realizar la consulta");
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    mysqli_data_seek($resultado, 0);    

// ---- parte nueva. Recogemos todas las fechas de la consulta y creamos un array de fechas ---- //
    for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){        
            extract($fila);        
            $dato = $fila[0];
            echo $dato;
            echo " --- ";
            $Fechas = array($dato);         
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código actual estas sobrescribiendo el array cada vez que quieres guardar $dato.

Debes inicializar $Fechas fuera del bucle y ir añadiendo cada dato al array y no sobrescribir cada vez.

Aquí te dejo una posible solución:

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM $producto ORDER BY $parametro DESC LIMIT 10";        

$resultado = mysqli_query($miconexion, $consulta) or die("No se puede realizar la consulta");

$Fechas = array();

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){        
    $dato = $fila[0];
    echo $dato;
    echo " --- ";
    $Fechas[] = $dato;      
}
```